# Mac OS available storage rapidly changing, shrinking

Tags: macos, troubleshooting, storage, disk-space, macos-catalina

I’ve been having an issue where the available storage on my disk lowers by up to several gb in a couple days, or fluctuates seemingly at random. On the latest version of Catalina, and so far I’ve tried:

-Reinstalling operating system

-Deleting and reinstalling operating system, then restoring FILES (not the full OS) from Time Machine

-Reindexing Spotlight (in case the computer was showing the wrong size)

-Removing large files and making sure everything looks normal through DaisyDisk

none of which worked.

If I restart the computer, or when I’ve updated software, it says it has more storage, but then starts decreasing again within a matter of days.

Please help, thanks!

Comment: "several gb in a couple days" really doesn't sound like much at all. Local Time Machine backups could easily account for that, or bird, getting ready to sync to iCloud. We need more detail to know why this appears to be an issue.

Comment: Understood - should have been more descriptive. The storage decreases sometimes very rapidly, and sometimes slower - I’ve seen it drop 10gb or more in two days, until I’m completely out of storage. 

If I then restart my computer when it thinks I’m out of storage, it sometimes shows a couple gb free, sometimes more, but then decreases again until I’m out.

Comment: So, what you actually mean is *your drive is too full*. 10GB space os a drive is simply not enough. You need 10 - 15% space & even more if you have a small drive, 256 or less.

Comment: Fair. But either way, I currently have (or had) about 40gb of storage, and then it'll go down all the way to 3 or 4gb of storage available. If I restart the computer, it'll show the 40gb open again.

Comment: DO you have 'Optimise Mac Storage' on in system prefs>iCloud>iCloud Drive Options…? if so, you are seeing intended behaviour. If not, then connect up Time Machine, let it run its backup, then you can clear any local backups if they didn't auto-clear. From your description, though, it sounds like the former.

Comment: Just had a chance to check - unfortunately no, Optimize Mac Storage was already off. Must be something else, any other ideas?